# Python 2D list slicing where one list is full of empty strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So say I have a 2D list like:

```
[
  [
    "9743",
    "user3"
  ],
  [
    "435",
    "user2"
  ],
  [
    "5426",
    "user8"
  ],
  [
    "",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "9743",
    "user9"
  ]
]
```

Where the index of that list of empty strings is unknown. Is there an easy way to slice the list so that everything after and including that list with empty strings is removed just keeping the stuff before it?

Comment: you need **both** items to be empty? or just one?

Comment: Any of them can be empty. For the actual 2D list, some of the values are different but that list has all of the strings empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that you have `['','']` try this:

```
lst = [[ "9743", "user3"],[ "435","user2"],["5426","user8"],["",""],["9743","user9"]]

lst[:lst.index(['',''])]
# Output
# [['9743', 'user3'], ['435', 'user2'], ['5426', 'user8']]
```

If you are not sure that you have `['','']` try this:

```
lst = [[ "9743", "user3"],[ "435","user2"],["5426","user8"],["9743","user9"]]
try:
    out = lst[:lst.index(['',''])]
except ValueError:
    out = lst
```

Output:

```
[['9743', 'user3'], ['435', 'user2'], ['5426', 'user8'], ['9743', 'user9']]
```

Comment: I think this one may be a bit faster than the accepted one, if less readable. From my testing, this one completes 100 iterations over my list in 0.01980050000000011 seconds and the accepted one completes 100 iterations over the same list in 0.11665389999999998 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.takewhile`:

```
from itertools import takewhile
list(takewhile(lambda x: x != ['', ''], the_list))
```

*NB. I named the list "the_list"*

output:

```
[['9743', 'user3'], ['435', 'user2'], ['5426', 'user8']]
```

If you want to stop at any item being `''`:

```
from itertools import takewhile
list(takewhile(lambda x: '' not in x, l))
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through each item in the list, slice the list when the empty value is found and break.

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
  if lst[i][0] == "" and lst[i][1] == "":
    lst = lst[:i]
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `iter` with sentinel:

```
list(iter(iter(lst).__next__, ['', '']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can lose a for-loop like this: (with x being your list)

```
output = []
for pair in x:
    if pair != ['', '']:
        output.append(pair)
    else:
        break   # Breaking as soon as there is an empty pair.
```

The output is:

```
[['9743', 'user3'], ['435', 'user2'], ['5426', 'user8']]
```